# How to determine at what speed a router will be able to handle VPN connection?

Tags: router, vpn, hardware-rec

When reading router description, how do I find at what speed a router will be able to handle VPN connection? They do not write this in description, and do not test this on reviews, so I must guess from hardware specs somehow. I need at least 60Mbit.

What I want to know, is if a newer SOHO router would manage 60Mbit, or if I would have to build my own router from PC components.

Comment: I know the question sounds extra stupid, but if I simply ask how to find a router for fast connection, they mark it offtopic.

Comment: That is dependent on your VPN provider. Which is not a question we can answer for you/

Comment: No, it is not. If I connect from PC directly, even Android Phone, my speed is 60Mbit, as per ISP limit. If I connect from router, however, it drops to 7Mbit. Router simply can't keep up with encrypting. What I want to know, however, is if a newer SOHO router would manage, or if I would have to build my own router from PC components.

Comment: Using a VPN doesn't mean you get that same ISP limit from your VPN provider.

Comment: Normally if you are using a VPN on a PC it is the PC that is doing the encrypting, not the router.

Comment: Both your remarks are true but irrelevant in my case. I need a router that can encrypt at 60Mbit, that's all. There are few models advertised "for VPN", but all of them are absent from local markets because they cost too much. I just hope that a bit cheaper solution can deal with it too. Otherwise, I'll build my own router: Simple PC, a couple of extra Ethernet cards, Linux...

Comment: Are you hosting the VPN? I think Davidpostill may be mis-understanding you. If you are not hosting, and not connecting the router as a client, his comments hold true. There are many factors, what's the encryption strength in bits? The higher the encryption in bits the more processing power is required.

Comment: Your use of "cost too much" doesn't help us here? How much is too much, you could go with pfsense, openWRT, dd-wrt. OpenWRT and DD-wrt can be put on a half decent consumer grade router to both host a VPN, and connect your local subnet to a VPN. The chosen model would be entirely dependant on the encryption in use. Pfsense can't be installed on consumer-grade routers, but works very well on old hardware.

Comment: A half-decent consumer grade router only handles 7Mbit. Reducing encryption to 128 bit does not help at all, because, most likely, AES is implemented in hardware anyway. What I want to do is to connect a remote worker into corporate network, but yes, I need to connect on a router, and I need speed.

Comment: Maybe on old wrtg54's... Go with a router that has has a multi core CPU over 1.2 ghz per core. Or go with pfsense on decent hardware. (Like a Dell power edge with Intel  NICS) If this is for business/Enterprise go with Enterprise equipment. Cisco, F5 networks, extreme networks, but you will pay Enterprise prices. Sometimes you can find this gear used for less if your company is cool with it.

Comment: A few things I'd like to note: The CPU frequency matters. Multi-core does not matter as dd-wrt in openvpn client mode is a single-core application. I have a dd-wrt router with a 480MHz CPU and I get a maximum of 8mbit/s. I'm looking for a replacement too, turns out routers with decent CPUs are a fortune. You are better off getting a raspberry pi and building your own router. This is what I'm planning on doing.